# Как в php получить остаток от деления с большей точностью?

Tags: php, kotlin

Есть простое выражение вычисляющее остаток от деления float:

```
123.001 % 1 // Получим 0.001 в kotlin
123.001 % 1 // Получим 0.0 в php
```

Если способ заставить php считать остаток от деления с большей точностью как это делает kotlin?

Использую php8 на macos

Comment: `fmod`? https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.fmod.php

Comment: @Kotomi Привет. Сделай в виде ответа. Я отмечу как решение. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для получения более точного остатка, используется функция [`fmod`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.fmod.php)
Test: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e90e85a6d265defa8f9228d12e07b965ae0aba44